# Can Foreign Key be unique as not to accept values more then once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question. I have created a parent table with multiple child tables and every time a record is inserted into the parent table my child tables get updated.  Here problem is my foreign is not unique and I want to make it as unique as not to accept values more then with same foreign id column. what is the process?

Comment: Will most or all of your rows have a foreign key value pointing to a row in the target table?

Comment: The foreign key guarantees the relationship to the parent table.  If you want unique values, add a unique constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can add a unique constraint to a column that is a foreign key.  Unless you are adding additional columns though this would likely result in a 1 to 1 relationship between parent and child instead of a 1 to many.  Is that what you desire?

To add a unique constraint to an existing table you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE schema.TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName UNIQUE (CommaSeperatedColumnList);
```

Comment: Yeah I need something like this which does not allow any entries into the child table with already existing foreign key value.. will try this.

Comment: If your FK column accepts NULL values, you may need to implement this as a unique filtered index. But the approach is sound.

Comment: am sure this is the same thing what I used but I dont need the new column, nywaz thanks for answering.. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
create table MyTable 
   (ID int foreign key references person.person(BusinessEntityID) unique,
   SomeOtherColumn varchar(100))
```

Comment: I dont want to add any new column to the table, only existing column needs to be updated. will try